# Symfony override autowired services

Tags: symfony, autowired

I'm writing a Symfony 4 bundle and inside, in a compiler pass, I create multiple service definitions based on an abstract one (also enabling autowiring based on the argument name):

```
    $managerDefinition = new ChildDefinition(Manager::class);
    $managerDefinition->replaceArgument(0, $managerName);
    ...
    $container->registerAliasForArgument($managerId, Manager::class, $managerName . 'Manager');
```

And this is the abstract service definition:

```
services:
    MyBundle\Manager:
        abstract: true
        arguments:
            - # manager name
```

So, in my App controller I can have this and it works correctly:

```
public function __construct(MyBundle\Manager $barManager)
{
    // $barManager is MyBundle\Manager
}
```

Now, let's say at some point I decide to extend the Manager class in my App with additional methods:

```
class MyManager extends \MyBundle\Manager
{
    public function newMethod() {
        ...
    }
}
```

I override the bundle's abstract service like this:

```
services:
    MyBundle\Manager:
        class: App\Manager
        abstract: true
        arguments:
            - # manager name
```

Everything still works as expected:

```
public function __construct(MyBundle\Manager $barManager)
{
    // $barManager is App\Manager

    $barManager->newMethod(); // Works
}
```

However, the IDE complains that **newMethod()** does not exist, as it doesn't exist in the typehinted **MyBundle\Manager**.

So, it seems more correct to change my constructor definition to let it know the actual class it's going to receive:

```
public function __construct(App\Manager $barManager)
```

However, I can't write this, as auto-wiring no longer works.

I suppose I could write a compiler pass in my App that registers autowiring for my custom **App\Manager**, but that seems like an overkill.

I can't shake the feeling that I'm doing something fundamentally wrong.

I guess my question is, what would be the best way to allow easy overriding of the abstract **Manager** definition in the bundle?